# Zoom bitmap image

Tags: c#, .net, aforge

This method work but i need to zoom to center of image, this method zoom to top left corner. Any one know how to help me.(bitmap from webcam stream)

```
        Bitmap orgignalbitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        Size newSize = new Size((orgignalbitmap.Width + zoomFactor), (orgignalbitmap.Height + zoomFactor));
        Bitmap tmpImage1 = new Bitmap(orgignalbitmap, newSize);
```

Comment: Use `Graphics.DrawImage` to draw a scaled image. By using the `originalBitmap` constructor of `Bitmap` you're only making a copy (and expanding the size of the canvas), you aren't actually performing any scaling operation of the image data.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, this is an example for 200% zoom at center

```
Bitmap originalBitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(); //cloning is not necessary
Bitmap tmpImage1 = new Bitmap(originalBitmap.Width, originalBitmap.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tmpImage1);
int left = originalBitmap.Width / 4;
int top = originalBitmap.Height / 4;
int width = originalBitmap.Width / 2;
int height = originalBitmap.Height / 2;
Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(left, top, width, height);
Rectangle dstRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, tmpImage1.Width, tmpImage1.Height);
g.DrawImage(originalBitmap, dstRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```